# Basic parsing of braces in Bash/sed/AWK

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed

Being from a math background, I've successfully Pavlov's-dogged myself into only being able to write in (Plain) TeX, so I often use TeX to do a lot of non-math text editing that people more commonly use MS Word or Google Docs to do. (Once you are used to the elegance of TeX-produced PDFs the clunkiness of word-processor typesetting really becomes an eyesore.) The issue arises once in a while when I'm asked to submit something in `.docx` format, which usually requires me to copy my TeX code over to a Google doc, spend a few minutes to half an hour manually making changes, and then export that as a `.docx` file. I have a little Bash function in my `.zshrc` that I use to do some of the really easy stuff (European accents and such) that I don't want to do by hand:

````
tex2doc() {
    (tr '\n' ' ' < $1.tex) |
    sed 's/  /\n\t/g' |
    sed "s/\\\'e/é/g" |
    sed "s/\\\^o/ô/g" |
    sed "s/\\\'E/É/g" |
    sed 's/```/“‘/g' |
    sed "s/'''/’”/g" |
    sed 's/``/“/g' |
    sed "s/''/”/g" |
    sed 's/`/‘/g' |
    sed "s/'/’/g" |
    sed 's/\\\"//g' |
    sed 's/\\~n/ñ/g' |
    sed 's/\~/ /g' |
    sed 's/\\ / /g' |
    sed 's/\\-//g' |
    sed 's/\\c{c}/ç/g' |
    sed 's/\\\///g' |
    sed 's/---/—/g' |
    sed 's/--/–/g' > $1.txt
}
````

With this stuff out of the way, what I'm left with is the (computationally) more complex task of converting italics from the format `{\it ... }` to maybe something like Markdown, so that I can open the Markdown in some kind of Markdown reader and just copy-paste that. This would be easy if I *only* ever used italics, but sometimes I might use bold, in the format `{\bf ... }`, or small caps, in the format `{\sc ... }`. So the functionality I might like is the following:

1. Upon seeing `{\it` , replace it with `_`.
2. Upon seeing `{\bf` , replace it with `**`.
3. Upon seeing `{\sc` , replace it with nothing. (I don't mind not having small caps in my `.doc` output.)
4. Upon seeing `}`, replace it with `_` if the last token encountered was a `{\it` , with a `**` if we last saw a `{\bf` , or nothing if we last saw a `{\sc` . (And then pop the "stack", however that's implemented.)

Because this is a (very simple form of) parsing, I considered using a Python-based lexer and parser to parse everything and then output Markdown, which I feel would take a while, and also it has been a super long time since I used `lex` and `yacc`. This also feels like using a sledgehammer to hang up a picture. Is there a simple "Bash-esque" solution to this problem? I know `sed` itself probably cannot solve this, since it's more for regexes, but maybe AWK might help. I've used AWK a bit in the past but I remember its syntax being quite obtuse and difficult, and also I'm not sure of its limitations, so I would appreciate any pointers! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: no answers, just a question/suggestion ... any luck with a web search on (something like) `convert tex docx markdown`?

Comment: Hi! thanks for the suggestion! Not much luck, sadly, because LaTeX is much more common online than Plain TeX.

Comment: For simple cases, something like `sed 's/{\\it\([^}]*\)}/_\1_/g; s/{\\bf\([^}]*\)}/**\1**/g'` should work.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I'm not well-versed enough in sed to understand what that command does---does it support nesting? Then again, I'm not sure _Markdown_ even supports nesting, so it might well be the best solution anyway.

Comment: This `sed` command doesn't support nested tags, but it is possible to make it support, though it is not so easy. I wouldn't use `sed` if nested tags are possible.

Comment: the proposed `sed` (as is) would require multiple invocations (potentially one 'repeat' for each level of nesting); consider `{\it ... {\bf ... {\it ... }}}` ... 1st time running the `sed` script you'd replace the inner `{\it`, 2nd (re)running of the `sed` script would replace the `{\bf`, and the 3rd (re)running of the `sed` script would replace the outer `{\it`

Comment: With markp-fuso's caveat, I think @M. Nejat Aydin's solution is good enough for my purposes (I definitely don't need arbitrary nesting). If you would convert your comment to an answer, with a little bit of explanation as to how it works, I would be happy to accept it!

Comment: It's not directly relevant to your question, but you can make your `sed` commands much more efficient by using the `-e` option to pass all the commands to a single `sed` invocation (i.e. `sed -e 's/  /\n\t/g' -e "s/\\\'e/é/g" -e "s/\\\^o/ô/g" -e ...`). Also, the parentheses around the `tr` command are useless, and create an unnecessary subshell. Finally, I recommend double-quoting parameter references (e.g. `"$1.tex"` instead of just `$1.tex`) to avoid parsing problems with funny characters in filenames.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson, I will make these changes.

Comment: As soon as you do `tr '\n' ' ' < $1.tex` you've turned the input into something that's no longer a valid text file per POSIX (no line endings) and so YMMV with what `sed` or any other text processing tool will do with it. And don't call `sed` 20 times, just call it (or, better, awk) once - instead of `sed s/foo/bar/g | sed 's/this/that/g'` you can write `sed 's/foo/bar/g; s/this/that/g'`. If you [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Comment: When providing your example make sure to include cases where the target strings such as `{\it` and `}` appear in contexts where you do NOT want them converted, assuming such exist and are escaped in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `GNU sed` and the original text doesn't contain a `BEL` character (ASCII 7):

```
sed '
    s/{\\/\a/g                  # replace each {\ with BEL character (\a)
:a
    s/\ait\([^}\a]*\)}/_\1_/g   # replace italics
    ta
    s/\abf\([^}\a]*\)}/**\1**/g # replace bolds
    ta
    s/\asc\([^}\a]*\)}/\1/g     # replace small caps
    ta
    s/\a/{\\/g
'
```

This version supports nesting. Each `s` command replaces the inner-most `{\xx ... }`.

Comment: possible issue with standalone braces; using `sample.tex` (from my answer) ... this answer generates `_{thin_**_}` instead of `_{thin}_**_`

Comment: @markp-fuso In `{\it{thin}`, the `}` closes the `{\it`, so it seems normal to me. I think an escape mechanism should be specified in order to write a literal `}` if it is enclosed in `{\xx ...}`

Comment: guess that would depend on what the user intends re: formatting; I was looking at the `}` as closing out the `{thin`; 'course, user could have intended the `{thin}` to have separate formatting ... one set of formats for `{thin` and no format for the literal `}`

Answer (score 3):

Sample data stream coming from OP's series of `sed` calls:

```
$ cat sample.tex
nothing to do on this line
this line {\itis just {\bfmade up {\scout of {\it{thin}}}}} air
nothing to do on this line
```

One `GNU awk` (for 4th arg to `split()`) idea:

```
$ cat tex.awk

BEGIN  { map["\\it"]="_"                                                    # populate our replacements array
         map["\\bf"]="**"
         map["\\sc"]=""
         delete stack                                                       # designate "stack" as an array
         s=0                                                                # index for stack[] array; default value is "0" so do not need this line except for documentation
       }

/[{}]/ { n = split($0,data,/[{}]/,seps)                                     # if line contains braces then split on braces; data goes into data[], delimiters go into seps[]
         newline = data[1]                                                  # initialize new line of output to anything before first delimiter

         for (i=2;i<=n;i++) {                                               # loop through rest of parsed data
             if (seps[i-1] == "}") {                                        # if delimiter is "}" then ...
                newline = newline stack[s--] data[i]                        # pop associated string off stack[]
             }
             else {                                                         # delimiter is "{"
                f3 = substr(data[i],1,3)                                    # get first 3 characters
                if (f3 in map) {                                            # if f3 is an index in map[] then ...
                   newline = newline map[f3] substr(data[i],length(f3)+1)   # append map[] replacement and rest of data to our new line of output
                   stack[++s] = map[f3]                                     # push associated map[] value on stack
                }
                else {                                                      # delimiter is standalone "{" so ...
                   newline = newline "{" data[i]                            # (effectively) do nothing but append to new line
                   stack[++s] = "}"                                         # push closing brace on stack[]
                }
             }
         }
         print newline
         next
       }
1                                                                           # line does not contain any braces so just print as is
```

**NOTES:**

- assumes all replacements are based on exactly 3 characters; replacements for fewer, or more, characters could be added with undertanding that the testing logic would need to be expanded beyond the current `f3` code
- assumes braces come in pairs (ie, each `{` has a matching `}`, and vice versa)
- assumes the same formatting applied to a matching pair of standalone braces, eg, with `{\it{thin}` the `}` matches the `{thin` and not the `{\it` (though source *could* have meant to apply a different format to `{thin` and `}` in which case the `}` would match the `{\it`)
- once `awk` is pulled into the mix it would be possible to pull all of the current `sed` code into the same `awk` script, though OP may be more comfortable maintaining the current `sed` as is

We'll use `cat sample.tex` to simulate the output coming from OP's series of `sed` calls:

```
$ cat sample.tex
nothing to do on this line
this line {\itis just {\bfmade up {\scout of {\it{thin}}}}} air
nothing to do on this line

$ cat sample.tex | awk -f tex.awk
nothing to do on this line
this line _is just **made up out of _{thin}_**_ air
nothing to do on this line
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not reinvent wheel and trying [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) which does allow for conversion between various formats, but with **WARNING** that you must limit yourself to such TeX documents which are valid LaTeX documents. If you are unable to comply with such requirement you would probably need to find another way, possible multi-stage one (e.g. TeX > HTML > docx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I will probably not start using LaTeX just to be able to convert things to Markdown. And the conversion to HTML would largely be the same problem as converting to Markdown in the first place.